# arrow function error when use jQuery map function

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrow-functions

Why it can't work when i use

```
$('.pc-nav>li').map((x)=>$(x).text())
```

to get innerText while

```
$('.pc-nav>li').map(function(){return $(this).text()})
```

is ok?

Comment: What browser are you trying to use this on? `=>` is not supported on IE

Comment: [When someone asks a question about a problem with their code, we need to know what is wrong with it. Stating that “it doesn’t work” is not helpful.](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/)

Comment: `$(x)` is not the same as `$(this)`

Comment: I'm using Chrome.

Comment: First step when something doesn't work as expected? -> read the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/map/)...

Comment: and the console and then tell us what the console says. Like I said, “it doesn’t work” is not helpful.

Comment: @liam there is no error in the code. `$(1).text()` will fail silently and will return `""`

Comment: Read the documentation for `collection.map( (index, item) => {})` http://api.jquery.com/map/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cause `x` is not the element, but its position (index) in the collection. Take the second argument (the actual element which you want):

```
$('.pc-nav>li').map((pos, el) => $(el).text())
```

And next time, check [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/map/) first...

Comment: They may have been reading the [jQuery.map](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) docs since it's the first result when you search `jquery map` where the arguments are switched.